# Validate time as 24 hours from now in php, option select in html

Tags: php, html

I cannot figure this one out. I have a HTML date that the user can select and below the hour for delivery. The date must be not today or before today, that part is fine but the time i cannot work out. It must be 24 hours from the current time.

Here is what i have:

```
if (!isset($_POST["pickupTime"])) {
$pickupTimeErr = "Pickup Time is required";
} elseif (date('h:i:sa', strtotime($_POST["pickupTime"]))  <= date('h:i:sa', strtotime('+ 24 hours') )) {
$pickupTimeErr = "Time must be greater than 24hours from now";
} else {
$pickupTime = test_input($_POST["pickupTime"]);
}


<p>Preferred Time:
            <select name="pickupTime">
                <option>Hour</option>
                <option value="7:00">7:00</option>
                <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
                <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
                <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
                <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $pickupTimeErr;?></span></p>
            Minute: <input type="text" name="pickupTime">
```

The preferred pickup time needs to be within 7:30 and 20:30. Also with the preferred time, is there a way to iterate over times and input them into the options?

I'm sure there is an easier way, this does not work. Please help.